# Styling a select input in CSS like rent.com

Tags: css, forms

Does anyone know of a pretty much native select plugin for styling `<select>`. What I mean by native is that you interactive with the 'select' box itself not some flux `select` created with `UL` or `DIV`, which seems to be the way most select plugins handle this. The best example I can find is http://www.rent.com; on that site when you click the flux `a` you end up interacting with the `select` element. It's perfect, it's responsive and you don't have to pass event listeners around if your dealing with complex javascript.

Looking through the source I can't work out how it's done, I know it has something to do with the `label` wrapping the `select`. This has padding which covers the complete `select` box. Does anyone now how this is done is it a JS plugin or just some CSS magic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main parts to their solution:

1. They set the `opacity` of the `select` to 0 so you don't see the select at all until it's been clicked (and even then you only see the drop down panel). It has been manipulated to sit directly over the `a` tag described in step 2 so that it still handles click events.
2. There is a sibling `a` tag that has been modified to look nice (rounded gray border, nice font, css-generated drop down arrow, etc). When the value of the `select` is changed, javascript takes the selected value and updates the text inside of the `a`.

I put together a quick fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/RKeks/. I did use a `label` rather than an `a` element on mine.

Comment: Thanks Jason this is just was I was looking for. My only tiny little issue with your fiddle is that if you click on the arrow itself it doesn't open the select dropdown ):

Comment: I didn't spend much time on it. It's probably a `z-index` problem. Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/RKeks/2/

Answer (score 1):

I've look in to it and it seems like the opacity of the select is set to 0 so you can't see the ugly default look of it and it's also position absolute on top of the other pretty zone.

Answer (score 1):

You're not seeing the `select`, if you use Chrome-devtools you can drag the html parts apart and see it more easily.

The arrow you're seeing is inside the `<a>`, it's `<span class="icon i-right i-triangle-down-white"></span>`

The label is probably to make it selectable outside the small strip of the select itself.